# passing defines through Java to the Google Closure Compiler

Tags: java, javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

As the title says, I'd like to pass defines programmatically via the Java API to the Google Closure Compiler.

This is my current code:

```
com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Level.INFO);
com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler compiler = new com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler();
CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
CompilationLevel.ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);
WarningLevel.VERBOSE.setOptionsForWarningLevel(options);

List<JSSourceFile> externs = new ArrayList<JSSourceFile>();
externs.add(JSSourceFile.fromFile(extern_src));

List<JSSourceFile> primary = new ArrayList<JSSourceFile>();
primary.add(JSSourceFile.fromFile(tmp));
compiler.compile(externs, primary, options);
for (JSError message : compiler.getWarnings()) {
    System.err.println("Warning message: " + message.toString());
}

for (JSError message : compiler.getErrors()) {
    System.err.println("Error message: " + message.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to populate the [define replacements map](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#819).

```
options.getDefineReplacements().put("myDefineVarName", value);
```

The value has to be a `Node` that is a boolean, numeric, or string literal.
To create a value for a boolean literal use a value like

```
new Node(Token.TRUE)
```

where both `Node` and `Token` are from the package `com.google.javascript.jscomp.rhino`.

I believe `Token.STRING` and `Token.NUMBER` are the token types for the other kinds of values but don't quote me on that.